# Expanding and collapsing tableView sections iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uigesturerecognizer

I am able to expand and collapse the tableView sections successfully however I am not able to do it for individual sections so far.So all the sections collapse or expand at the same time, which is because I call `[tableView reloadData]` .So How can I expand or collapse a particular section?

Here is how I am doing it currently.

```
  -(UIView*)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
  {
     headerLabel = [[UILabel alloc]init];
     headerLabel.tag = section;
     headerLabel.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
     headerLabel.backgroundColor = [[UIColor grayColor]colorWithAlphaComponent:0.2];
     headerLabel.text = [menuCategoryArray objectAtIndex:section];
     headerLabel.frame = CGRectMake(5, 0, tableView.tableHeaderView.frame.size.width, tableView.tableHeaderView.frame.size.height);


     UITapGestureRecognizer *tapGesture = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc]initWithTarget:self action:@selector(headerClicked:)];
     tapGesture.cancelsTouchesInView = NO;
     [headerLabel addGestureRecognizer:tapGesture];

     return headerLabel;


 }

 -(void)headerClicked:(UIGestureRecognizer*)sender
 {

    if (!isShowingList) {
    isShowingList=YES;
    [self.menuTableView reloadData];
    UILabel *lbl = (UILabel*)sender.view;
    NSLog(@"header no : %d", lbl.tag);

   }else{

    isShowingList=NO;
    [self.menuTableView reloadData];
    UILabel *lbl = (UILabel*)sender.view;
    NSLog(@"header no : %d", lbl.tag);

  }


  }

 - (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section{

if (isShowingList) {

    return [[[[jsonArray valueForKey:@"menus"] valueForKey:@"menuName"] objectAtIndex:section] count];

}else{
    return 0;
}
return 0;

}
```

Comment: for expanding use **insertRowsAtIndexPaths:withRowAnimation:** and for collapsing use **deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:withRowAnimation:**

Comment: So it should be used in headerClicked method ri8?How to get array of indexPaths then, for inserting?

Comment: Convert `isShowingList` into an array (or possibly a mutable array, if you have a variable number of sections).  Then use `section` as an index to the array to determine whether each section should be expanded.  You can determine which section header was tapped by testing the tag of the view of the gesture recogniser.

Comment: would really appreciate your explanation with some sample code, helps me to understand better :-]

Comment: give me an hour i'll provide you with my code

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First take `isShowingList` as

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray *isShowingList;
```

And for identifying previously opened section you need another property

```
@property (nonatomic, assign) NSInteger openSectionIndex;
```

when you have the data initialized, isShowingList in you case, initialize `isShowingList` array before reloading table

```
self.isShowingList = [NSMutableArray array];
if (jsonArray && [jsonArray valueForKey:@"menus"] && [[jsonArray valueForKey:@"menus"] valueForKey:@"menuName"]) {
    for (int i = 0; i < [[[jsonArray valueForKey:@"menus"] valueForKey:@"menuName"] count]; i++) {
        [self.isShowingList addObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:NO]];
    }
}
```

and initialize `openSectionIndex` in `viewDidLoad()` like this

```
self.openSectionIndex = NSNotFound;
```

and your code should be changed like this

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    if ([[self.isShowingList objectAtIndex:section] boolValue]) {
        return [[[[jsonArray valueForKey:@"menus"] valueForKey:@"menuName"] objectAtIndex:section] count];
    } else {
        return 0;
    }
    return 0;
}

-(void)headerClicked:(UIGestureRecognizer*)sender {
    UILabel *lbl = (UILabel*)sender.view;
    NSLog(@"header no : %d", lbl.tag);
    if ([[self.isShowingList objectAtIndex:lbl.tag] boolValue]) {
        [self closeSection:lbl.tag];
    } else {
        [self openSection:lbl.tag];
    }
}

//methods for expanding and collapsing sections
- (void)openSection:(NSInteger)section {
    [self.isShowingList replaceObjectAtIndex:section withObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:YES]];
    NSInteger countOfRowsToInsert = [[[[jsonArray valueForKey:@"menus"] valueForKey:@"menuName"] objectAtIndex:section] count];
    NSMutableArray *indexPathsToInsert = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    for (NSInteger i = 0; i < countOfRowsToInsert; i++) {
        [indexPathsToInsert addObject:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:i inSection:section]];
    }
    NSMutableArray *indexPathsToDelete = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    NSInteger previousOpenSectionIndex = self.openSectionIndex;
    if (previousOpenSectionIndex != NSNotFound) {
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            [self.menuTableView reloadSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:previousOpenSectionIndex] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];
        });
        [self.isShowingList replaceObjectAtIndex:previousOpenSectionIndex withObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:NO]];
        NSInteger countOfRowsToDelete = [[[[jsonArray valueForKey:@"menus"] valueForKey:@"menuName"] objectAtIndex:previousOpenSectionIndex] count];
        for (NSInteger i = 0; i < countOfRowsToDelete; i++) {
            [indexPathsToDelete addObject:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:i inSection:previousOpenSectionIndex]];
        }
    }
    // Apply the updates.
    [self.menuTableView beginUpdates];
    [self.menuTableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:indexPathsToInsert withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];
    [self.menuTableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:indexPathsToDelete withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];
    [self.menuTableView endUpdates];
    self.openSectionIndex = section;
}

- (void)closeSection:(NSInteger)section {
    [self.isShowingList replaceObjectAtIndex:section withObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:NO]];
    NSInteger countOfRowsToDelete = [self.menuTableView numberOfRowsInSection:section];
    if (countOfRowsToDelete > 0) {
        NSMutableArray *indexPathsToDelete = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
        for (NSInteger i = 0; i < countOfRowsToInsert; i++) {
            [indexPathsToDelete addObject:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:i inSection:section]];
        }
        [self.menuTableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:indexPathsToDelete withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationTop];
    }
    self.openSectionIndex = NSNotFound;
}
```

Comment: your open/close section methods are fragile because you are altering self.isShowingList OUTSIDE of the tableViewUpdates. inconsistencies between the model and the table outside of one of these update blocks are dangerous. I suggest you cut/paste the beginUpdates call to before you alter this array, see my example above (which is similar to your own otherwise) I understand that it runs for you without error, because you call beginUpdates immediately after altering the array, the user has just touched up, and is unlikely to be scrolling.. but it is not a perfect design imho. best regards :)

Comment: @Pratyusha : Thanks .Your method is perfect and its working fine, except for one thing.When I collapse a section, the data from the first row of that section, seem to float over the section title for just a fraction, and then it disappears.

Comment: try different animations in the add/delete cell methods there, where he has used UITableViewRowAnimationTop & UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic

Comment: Thank you for accepting my answer @icodes and as Jef suggested please try different animation that may solve your problem and also move beginUpdates call to before altering array as he suggested. Thank you for your suggestion Jef i'll take care next time

Answer (score 5):

You really would be better off looking at using a 'tableView update block'. Please take a look at this viewController for an answer I posted very recently.  The updateBlock allows you to manipulate some variable or other which affects the dataSource, and instruct the table to add/remove rows/sections in order to reflect that change.  Note that when you call the endUpdates method the table must not conflict with the model or you'll get an exception.

```
#import "ViewController.h"

//dont worry, the header is empty except for import <UIKit/UIKit.h>, this is a subclass on UIViewController

@interface ViewController ()<UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate>

@property (weak, nonatomic) UITableView *tableView;


@end

@implementation ViewController
{
//ivars
  BOOL sectionIsOpen[4]; //we will use this BOOL array to keep track of the open/closed state for each section.  Obviously I have the number of sections fixed at 4 here, but you could make a more dynamic array with malloc() if neccesary..
}



- (void)viewDidLoad {
  [super viewDidLoad];

  UITableView *tv = [[UITableView alloc]initWithFrame:self.view.bounds style:UITableViewStyleGrouped];
  tv.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth;
  tv.dataSource = self;
  tv.delegate = self;

  [self.view addSubview:tv];
  self.tableView = tv;

  // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

#pragma mark - UITableViewDataSource
-(NSInteger )numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView{
  return 4;
}

-(NSInteger )tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section{
  return ((sectionIsOpen[section]) ? [self numberOfRowsInSection:section] : 0);
}
-(NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section{

  //put your switch() here...

  return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"I am section %i", (int)section ];
}
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

  static NSString *cellId = @"cellID";

  UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellId];

  if (!cell) {
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:cellId];
  }


 //etc etc decorate your cell...
  cell.textLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"cell %i / %i", (int)indexPath.section, (int)indexPath.row ];


  return cell;
}
#pragma mark - UITableViewDelegate
-(UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section{

  const CGRect fr = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320.0, 40.0 );

  UIButton *btn = [[UIButton alloc]initWithFrame:fr];
  [btn setTitle:[self tableView:tableView titleForHeaderInSection:section] forState:UIControlStateNormal ];
  [btn setTag:section];
  [btn addTarget:self action:@selector(sectionOpenToggle:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];


  // add an image, colour etc if you like

  return btn;
}



#pragma mark - tableViewHelpers

//the number of rows in sectionX when it is open...
-(NSInteger )numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger )section{
//get your count from your model
  return section + 1;
}

//opening/closing a section
-(void )setSection:(NSInteger )section toOpen:(BOOL )open{

  if (open != sectionIsOpen[section]) {

//build an array of indexPath objects
    NSMutableArray *indxPths = [NSMutableArray array];
    for (NSInteger row = 0; row < [self numberOfRowsInSection:section]; row ++) {

      [indxPths addObject: [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:row inSection:section ]
       ];

    }


    [self.tableView beginUpdates];

    if (open) {
      [self.tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:indxPths withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
      //nb there is a large ENUM of tableViewRowAnimation types to experiment with..

    }else{
      [self.tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:indxPths withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];

    }
    sectionIsOpen[section] = open;
    [self.tableView endUpdates];

  }
}

-(void )sectionOpenToggle:(id )sender{
  [self setSection:[sender tag] toOpen: !sectionIsOpen[[sender tag]] ];
}

// open/close all sections.
-(void )setAllSectionsOpen:(BOOL )open{

  for (NSInteger section = 0; section < [self numberOfSectionsInTableView:self.tableView]; section ++) {
    [self setSection:section toOpen:open];
  }
}


//these two for your convenience, hook up to navbar items etc..
-(IBAction)openAllSections:(id)sender{
  [self setAllSectionsOpen:YES];
}
-(IBAction)closeAllSections:(id)sender{
  [self setAllSectionsOpen:NO];
}
@end
```