# how to create expand and collapse tableview?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

I am able to expand and collapse the tableView sections successfully however I am not able to do it for individual sections so far.So all the sections collapse or expand at the same time.

Comment: This question has been asked here many times.  See my answer to this one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27729150/expanding-and-collapsing-tableview-sections-ios/27730342#27730342

Answer (score 1):

You can collapse and expand `tableView` section by removing and adding `tableViewCells` on demand, like if you want to collapse reload that tableViewSection data and return zero in `numberOfRowsInSection`, and when you want to expand it back just return right amount of rows from `numberOfRowsInSection` method, it should be something like below

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    //Check if section is collapsed
    if (section_is_collapsed) return 0;
    return actual_num_of_rows_in_Section;
}
```