# How can I make expandable cells with dynamic content in swift?

Tags: ios, json, swift, uitableview, uicollectionview

Can you please tell me how can I create those in swift?
I have json that looks like this:

```
{
    1 = [
      title = "A",
      title = "B",
      title = "C"
    ],
    2 = [
      title = "A",
      title = "B"
    ],
    3 = [
      title = "D",
      title = "E",
      title = "F",
      title = "G"
    ]
}
```

I need to make a tableView with it that shows only cells with numbers. After I click on the cell it expands and shows different cells with letters after it. Also I have UILabel at the top of the tableView that changes it title with letter when I click on the letter cell.

JSON can change so I need to create dynamic model.

Thank you! Sorry if this question was already asked, but I can't find specific guide for this type of situation. Thank you again.

Comment: refer this link, [Expandable cell](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26217480/expand-cell-when-tapped-in-swift) hope this will help you.

Comment: You can refer [Git example](https://github.com/jeantimex/ios-swift-collapsible-table-section)

Comment: ok  i want to do same thing and done with solution  Of  @jef there easy and working  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27729150/expanding-and-collapsing-tableview-sections-ios